# How to map mongo subdocuments in GraphQL resolve? I get NULL

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to fetch a set of records in my mongo database using `mongoose` and send it to the GraphQL resolve function. I can get the documents. But the subdocuments always return null. If there are no sub-documents I get an empty array. For example, my data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: '2222dhjshjshfjfsf',
    address: 'dgdgdsf',
    contactNumber: 'dgdgsdfs',
    logo: 'sfsf',
    billingDetails: 'fdsfsdf',
    assignedEmployee: 'sff',
    keyContactPersons:
    [ { name: 'gdgdg',
        contactNumber: 'dgdfg',
        email: 'gdgdfgdfgdsff@gmail.com',
    } ],
    active: true,
    },
    ...
]
```

My resolve function looks like this:

```
const Company = mongoose.model('Company', new mongoose.Schema(), 'companies');

export default {
  Query: {
    companies: () =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        Company.find({})
          .lean()
          .exec((error, doc) => {
            if (error) {
              reject(error);
            }

            resolve(doc);
          }))
  }
};
```

This is the schema:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type KeyContactPerson {
    name: String!
    contactNumber: String
    email: String
  }

  type Company {
    slug: String!
    name: String
    address: String
    contactNumber: String
    logo: String
    billingDetails: String
    assignedEmployee: String
    keyContactsPersons: [KeyContactPerson]
    active: String
  }

  type Query {
    company(_id: ID!): Company
    companies: [Company]
  }
`;

export default makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});
```

When I console log the data `doc` returned from the find method, it has the correct values. The problem seems to be with the type definition. Here's a sample output I get from my GraphQL query:

```
{
  "data": {
    "companies": [
      {
        "slug": "abc-4",
        "name": "abc",
        "keyContactsPersons": []
      },
      {
        "slug": "abc-5",
        "name": "abc",
        "keyContactsPersons": null
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

The first record does not have any `keyContactsPersons` which is the subdocument. It returns an empty array. The second one has some values. But it returns null. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check your data at mongodb? One field could be an empty array and the other could be null

Comment: @AlessanderFrança Yes I did. The fields I'm requesting have data.

Comment: Did you log "console.log(doc)" before resolve(doc) to check if your data is ok?

Comment: @AlessanderFrança I got the data I posted above from that.

Comment: I think you could be wrote keyContactPersons instead of keyContacstPersons. In your example data you write 'keyContactPersons', but in your typedef you write 'keyContactsPersons'

Comment: @AlessanderFrança Oh thank you very much. Yes, it was the problem. Really sorry... :-)

Comment: This could happen with somebody ;)